# Search string without considering apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm using MS Sql database

While searching name keywords link  "blandy's" will get the result from table

I need to get same result while search keyword "blandys" (Without apostrophe )

How do I get the result?

Please help me?

Comment: `Replace`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Escape it with another apostroph

Comment: I think you can use a collation on that specific column to ignore them

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the apostrophe both from the search term and the keyword:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE REPLACE(keyword, '''', '') = REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '''', '')
```